# Upgrading C# project from VS 2010 to 2013; need to make it work for Windows 8 and 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, operating-system, upgrade

I inherited a C# app written in Visual Studio 2010 professional. From the compile done in VS 2010, the C# app works perfectly in Windows XP and Windows 7.

Now I am about to install Visual Studio 2013 for the first time tomorrow, and load the C# app.

I have 2 immediate goals:

- Upgrade my project to work in VS 2013 Professional. I am not sure
  if/what obstacles I may run into here, but if anyone has any suggestions I am all ears.
- More importantly, I have 2 new prospective users for my app - one wants to use it in   Windows 10, the other in Windows 8. However, I don't know the steps I
  have to take to make my C# app work for these newer operating
  systems. Are there specific steps I will have to take (or settings to
  assign) in Visual Studio 2013 so that my C# app will work for Windows
  8 and Windows 10? If someone knows the answer to this, can you please
  make it clear whether I should be making separate builds for each
  target operating system, or if the steps you suggest will allow me to
  build this for all 4 operating systems included in the same build?

Thanks very much, really appreciate any input.

Adam

Answer (score 0):

For the most part the project should auto update just fine. You might want to make a back up incase it upgrades incorrectly and it doesn't create a back up on its own.

The boxes you deploy to might need a visual studio 2013 redistributable which will be apparent if they crash when opening on the deployment machine